# Why Google public DNS(8.8.8.8)'s ping latency so low?

Tags: dns, ping, host, low-latency

I use [just-ping](http://just-ping.com) to ping Google public DNS server, which IP is 8.8.8.8. 
[just-ping](http://just-ping.com) can ping a host from 50 locations worldwide.

I found that DNS's latency is low around the world. Many cities are far from each other, but they got the same low latency in ping (about 5ms).

I suppose the IP 8.8.8.8 is directed to one host. How that host reacts so fast even it is faraway from its clients?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you Google "Google Public DNS latency"? See https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/performance and in particular https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/performance#geography

Comment: this is not programming related.

Comment: Maybe https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ would be a better fit? Although the tags make it seem like it would be on topic here as well.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

8.8.8.8 is **not** one host. Instead it's an [anycast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast) address which routed to the nearest host out of many locations around the world.